# Is it possible to order by the total count of multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I can't get this query to work!

```
return Post::selectRaw('likes_count + comments_count as total_count')
            ->withCount(['likes', 'comments'])
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->orderByDesc('total_count')
            ->paginate();
```

It works this way below but I want all the counts and something performant!

```
return Post::leftJoin('likes', function ($join) {
            $join->on('posts.id', 'likes.likable_id')
                ->where('likes.likable_type', (new Post)->getMorphClass());
        })->leftJoin('comments', function ($join) {
            $join->on('posts.id', 'comments.commentable_id')
                ->where('comments.commentable_type', (new Post)->getMorphClass());
        })
            ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(likes.id) + count(comments.id) as total_count')
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->orderByDesc('total_count')
            ->paginate();
```

Comment: @Berto99 I mean the first query doesn't work, it throws this error
```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes_count' in 'field list'

Comment: @Berto99 I just wanna get rid of some appends that count the total likes and comments, and do everything in 1 query for the optimal performance!

Comment: @Berto99 this is the log https://gist.github.com/chadidi/4a7366643aa1d2a39cdb4ad6e1e2767f

I have 3 eager loads and 4 appends.
I have all the keys indexed.

Comment: The log: https://gist.github.com/chadidi/d80c324fcea7b4ed4e1f3deaaa024b2f

Comment: Ok I have it without appends and Eagerloads: https://gist.github.com/chadidi/381fd23ea6b8ae5676a32b9273fa1348

Comment: Ok, please check the answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to change a little bit the first query:

```
return Post::selectRaw('Count(likes.id) + Count(comments.id) as total_count')
        ->withCount(['likes', 'comments'])
        ->groupBy('posts.id')
        ->orderByRaw('(Count(likes.id) + Count(comments.id)) desc')
        ->paginate();
```

Comment: i don't think that this code might works .. there is no column called likes_count or comments_count, loading them doesn't make them columns ... you need to join there tables and select them...

Comment: @OMR yes sorry, 
I forgot to change it

Comment: Just want to avoid counting tables multiple times as we have `>withCount(['likes', 'comments'])` I was asking if we can SUM those counts and order by them! I think it's not possible, by the way, I tried subqueries too, not working :(

Comment: @AbdellahChadidi DBMS will optimize it for you, if you count one thing 2 times, it will cache the result... test it (write a raw query with the 2 counts and only one, and you will see they run in the same time)

Comment: NO, but this query is no different from the second query I wrote!

Comment: @AbdellahChadidi well... it's a little bit prettier... ahah however how i said, DBMS will optimize it for you, and if it is so important, consider making some indexes

Comment: @Berto99 I am thinking of using something other than MySQL at the moment as I am building a feed, maybe I will use Redis or getstream.io. thanks for your help!