# Laravel orderByRaw count column not exits

Tags: sql, laravel, count, relationship

I have a Laravel API in which I want to provide a list of hashtags with the count of posts and comments in which a hashtag is used and order the list by the total count of posts and comments.

Here are my tables: `posts`, `comments`, `hashtags`, `hashtag_post`, `comment_hashtag`. Also, proper relationship methods are defined in my models.

After reading the Laravel's documentation and searching the web, I wrote this code:

```php
Hashtag::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])
    ->orderByRaw('posts_count + comments_count desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

If I use `orderBy` with only `posts_count` or `comments_count` alone, the query works and I get a list, but with the above code, I get this error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "posts_count" does not exist ...
```

I've used tinker to see if those columns are defined properly on the SQL query, and here's what I've got:

```sql
select "hashtags".*, (select count(*) from "posts" inner join "hashtag_post" on "posts"."id" = "hashtag_post"."post_id" where "hashtags"."id" = "hashtag_post"."hashtag_id" and "posts"."deleted_at" is null) as "posts_count", (select count(*) from "comments" inner join "comment_hashtag" on "comments"."id" = "comment_hashtag"."comment_id" where "hashtags"."id" = "comment_hashtag"."hashtag_id" and "comments"."deleted_at" is null) as "comments_count" from "hashtags" where "hashtags"."deleted_at" is null order by posts_count + comments_count desc
```

I've searched the web about the error, but I found nothing useful.

**Edit 1**: Based on @Ersoy comment I've changed my query as follow:

```php
Hashtag::selectRaw('Count(posts.id) + Count(comments.id) as total_count')
    ->withCount(['posts', 'comments'])
    ->groupBy('hashtags.id')
    ->orderByRaw('(Count(posts.id) + Count(comments.id)) desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

And as I expected, it didn't work. It says:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "posts"
```

The thing is, `likes` and `comments` in the other question, as I understand from the query, are 1-N relationships while my relationships are N-M. Also, I think using the `Count` function like that won't work without a join. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Edit 2**: One of my friends gave me this SQL query which gives the result I want:

```sql
select
    h.*,
    count(distinct hp.post_id) as posts_count,
    count(distinct ch.comment_id) as comments_count
from
    hashtags as h
left join hashtag_post as hp on
    h.id = hp.hashtag_id
left join posts p on
    hp.post_id = p.id
left join comment_hashtag ch on
    h.id = ch.hashtag_id
left join comments c on
    ch.comment_id = c.id
where
    h.deleted_at is null
    and p.deleted_at is null
    and c.deleted_at is null
group by
    h.id
order by
    ( count(distinct hp.post_id) + count(distinct ch.comment_id) ) desc;
```

But I don't know how to convert it properly to an Eloquent query.

Comment: This question is similar to yours - maybe the answer help? [Is it possible to order by the total count of multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182454/is-it-possible-to-order-by-the-total-count-of-multiple-tables)

Comment: @Ersoy I edited my question regarding your comment.

Comment: How about putting double quotes around the column names in the `order by` clause, like: `Hashtag::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])
    ->orderByRaw('"posts_count" + "comments_count" desc')
    ->paginate(15);`

Comment: @GMB It results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works perfectly if the Laravel version is 6+:

```php
Hashtag::withCount(['posts', 'comments'])
    ->orderByRaw('posts_count + comments_count desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

However, I'm currently using Laravel 5.7 and I can't upgrade it now. Thus I should use an alternative to get the desired result:

```php
Hashtag::leftJoin('hashtag_post as hp', 'hashtags.id', '=', 'hp.hashtag_id')
    ->leftJoin('posts as p', 'hp.post_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->leftJoin('comment_hashtag as ch', 'hashtags.id', '=', 'ch.hashtag_id')
    ->leftJoin('comments as c', 'ch.comment_id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->whereNull('p.deleted_at')
    ->whereNull('c.deleted_at')
    ->selectRaw('hashtags.*, count(distinct hp.post_id) as posts_count, count(distinct ch.comment_id) as comments_count')
    ->groupBy('hashtags.id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(distinct hp.post_id) + count(distinct ch.comment_id) desc')
    ->paginate(15)
```

Thanks to @tarun-jain

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('hashtags as h')
    ->leftJoin('hashtag_post as hp', 'h.id', '=' ,'hp.hashtag_id')
    ->leftJoin('posts as p', 'hp.post_id', '=' ,'p.id')
    ->leftJoin('comment_hashtag as ch', 'h.id', '=', 'ch.hashtag_id')
    ->leftJoin('comments as c', 'ch.comment_id', '=' ,'c.id')
    ->whereNull('h.deleted_at')
    ->whereNull('p.deleted_at')
    ->whereNull('c.deleted_at')
    ->selectRaw("*, count(distinct hp.post_id) + count(distinct ch.comment_id) as total_count")
    ->groupBy('h.id')
```

// try

```
    ->orderByRaw('count(distinct hp.post_id) + count(distinct ch.comment_id) desc')
```

// or

```
    ->orderByRaw('total_count desc')
    ->get();
```

Both the orderByRaw statement are similar, you can try any of the above. Hopefully, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test it and let you know the result.

Comment: The exact code does not work, because 1. You've selected all columns in all tables and group by complain about that. 2. I need posts' count and comments' count separated, only order must be based on their sum. However I modified code a bit and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I just overlooked it... I shared the eloquent for query structure... instead of * it should be `h.*, count(distinct hp.post_id) as posts_count, count(distinct ch.comment_id) as comments_count` and for using total_count in orderByRaw you have to pass it in the select as well.